# Google Analytics 4 - Refund transactions and Internal Traffic

Tags: google-analytics-4

I did full implementation of GA4 events include Refund transactions. Problem is, that my company has excluded traffic from internal IP's. Our admin page is on the one of these IP's. How to solve this situation?

I'm using gtag. I would like to send GA4, that refund is allowed. Something like "internal_traffic=false" which overwrite default value, defined in GA settings. But I cannot how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect second "Data Stream" (in Admin menu).

Second Data Stream will have separate unique GA tag, which you can use for triggering events (eg from Admin Area). Do not specify internal or debug traffic for this second data source and don't use it to count page views in your Admin Area. Use it only for triggering the "admin events", like 'refund'.

[image: Screenshot from Google Analytics]

Comment: Thank you Oleksii. Do you mean "data stream"?

Comment: Oh, yes, "Data stream", not "Data source" of course! Edited my answer.